# Peru Urevu Halacha question

Tags: halacha, technology, mitzvah, medicine, pregnancy-birth

If a jewish male donates sperm to a jewish couple who cannot have children for whatever purpose. By donating sperm does the donor fulfill the mitzvah of Peru Eruvu?

If the answer is yes, then the donator fulfilled his mitzvah (being he donated sperm which ended in a result of one boy and one girl) of Peru Eruvu, even though he was never married and does not have offsprings other than what he donated?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for the interesting question! As you saw in my other comment, this was already asked here. But I hope you'll look around and find other Q&A of interest and stay learning with us. And if you haven’t done so already, you should take a look at the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: Note also that there are many difficult questions with sperm donation from Jews (and poskim mostly forbid it due to potential issues with the status of the child, e.g., forbidden marriages) and non-Jews (also forbidden by a number of prominent poskim). See for instance http://dinonline.org/2010/12/27/sperm-donation/ and http://www.jewishfertility.org/egg-donation.php